# Spring (NOT BOOT) Load different application-{profile}.properties with profiles set in pom.xml

Tags: spring-mvc, properties, configuration

I'm trying to make a Spring **NON-BOOT** application to load two different application.properties files (dev and prod) based on the -Pdev or -Pprod params that i give when building with maven.

pom.xml

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>dev</id>
        <properties>
            <activatedProperties>dev</activatedProperties>
        </properties>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>prod</id>
        <properties>
            <activatedProperties>prod</activatedProperties>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

I have:

```
application.properties
application-dev.properties
application-prod.properties
```

I have the correct profiles specified in pom.xml but 
when i build the actual substitution is done in the application.properties but apparently Spring doesn't pick up by default the correct application-{profile}.properties at startup and i have no idea how to solve this problem...

This is the correct substitution in application.properties after i build with 
    mvn clean install -Pprod

```
spring.profiles.active=prod
```

Thank you for your help!